# Some questions regarding $GOPATH

Tags: go, gopath

I'm a new golang developer and I wonder why `$GOPATH` environment variable is needed to be set at the root of my project.

If I'm working on several projects at the same time, I need to each time re-set the `$GOPATH` environment variable to point to a different location.

In my setup, I have `$GOPATH` set to `/Users/Projects/go/lib`. which is a generic directory for all of my golang projects.

Just to clarify: the projects data is placed in `/Users/Projects/go/<Project Name>`

If anyhow all `$GOPATH` is used for (as far as I know) is to install 3rd party libraries, isn't it safe to have one `$GOPATH` directory for all my projects, so all the required 3rd party libraries are installed in the same lib directory, and whenever I compile on of the projects it just uses the libs it requires.

Is this bad in practice? Why?

Comment: You can put your projects in same directory. There shall be no problem.

Comment: This will clarify a lot of things - https://golang.org/doc/code.html
Note that the $GOPATH is considered as a "go workspace" which all go projects should be placed under the "src" sub dir. 
There are a lot of resources clarifying the use of $GOPATH.

Comment: Basically `GOPATH` refers to a "Go workspace" as Shikloshi stated, so you might find [Whats a good best practice with Go workspaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20722502/539810) to be an interesting read. It has different answers with different reasons for those answers. Personally I use the one-workspace scheme, but obviously that could vary based on project requirements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Q2 2018:
Note that with the **[vgo project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48914523/6309)**, `GOPATH` might end up being deprecated in favor of a project-based workflow. That would avoid the manual project-based `GOPATH` I was proposing below, two years ago)

With Go 1.11 (August 2018), **[`GOPATH` can be optional, with modules](https://golang.org/doc/go1.11#modules)**.

It is more and more supported with VSCode:

- [vscode-go/issue 1532](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/1532#issuecomment-424906159)
- "[Go modules support in Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/Go-modules-support-in-Visual-Studio-Code)"

---

June 2016: You don't have to rely on *only* one `GOPATH` (ie [one workspace](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces)).

My full `GOPATH` includes:

- a global path (for all utilities like `goimports`), [`github.com/smartystreets/goconvey`](https://github.com/smartystreets/goconvey), ...), in `$HOME/go` for instance,
- a local path (for my current project), where my local `src`, `pkg` and `bin` will be.

That is two paths:

```
export GOPATH=/path/to/myproject:$HOME/go
```

> Isn't it safe to have one $GOPATH directory for all my projects, so all the required 3rd party libraries are installed in the same lib directory, and whenever I compile on of the projects it just uses the libs it requires.
>
> Is this bad in practice? Why?

I don't like that practice, as different projects could require different *version* of the same library.
That is why I have one `GOPATH` per project, that my build script (versioned with the project) sets for me.

When I clone a go project of mine, I:

- set my `GOPATH` to that go project (local path, where the third-party libraries I need for that project will be installed, and moved to a `vendor` folder),
- make a symlink to that path `<myproject>/src/<myproject> -> ../..`, since `GOPATH` means go expects to find the sources of `myproject` in `src/<apackage>`.

That organization:

- remains compatible with `go get`,
- ensure any specific dependencies I need are installed by default in my project folder instead of being lost within the mass of global libraries/utilities present in the global `GOPATH`.

I have:

```
myproject
   mysource.go
   apackage
     othersource.go
   src
     myproject -> ../..
     vendor
        third-party packages
```

On Windows, a typical build script would be:

```
λ more b.bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if not defined GOROOT (
        echo Environment variable GOROOT must be defined, with %%GOROOT%%\bin\go.exe
        exit /b 1
)

set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
set PATH=%PATH%;%GOROOT%/bin
set GOPATH=%~dp0;%HOME%/go

set prjname=%GOPATH:~0,-1%
for %%i in ("%prjname%") do set "prjname=%%~ni"
rem echo prjname='%prjname%'

if not exist src (
        mkdir src
)
if not exist src\%prjname% (
        mklink /J src\%prjname% %GOPATH%
)

pushd %~dp0
cd src\%prjname%
rem cd
go install
popd
endlocal
```

Anyone cloning my go project would simply type '`b`'.

Comment: Awesome! That symbol link `myproject -> ../..` is exactly what I've been puzzled to figure out how to deal your own code that you do not want to put under the common directory that should contain only the third-party code. I've been thinking using two parts in the GOPATH for your own and the third-party but it runs into lots of trouble. One question though, how do you do that on MS-Windows?

Comment: @minghua But all that is obolete with Go modules now (1.11+): https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules

Comment: gopath is a mess, especially if you 're from a country that golang.org and github.com is sometimes blocked, every time after you use 3rd party tool bypass the network, like gopm, to checkout a go lib, the git versioning scheme will break since paths are changed by those tools, this means you will never get the lib updated properly, the only option is to reinstall every lib gets updated. With the new mod tool, no more path changing, just like happy npm.

Comment: @tomriddle_1234 I agree. And you can combine that with your own module URL repository: https://thumbai.app/ and https://github.com/thumbai/thumbai